# Teams activity teamIds are 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I have an application, with which to query Microsoft's API graph. When I run the GET query:

```
$url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/reports/getTeamsTeamActivityDetail(period='D90')"
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Headers @{ Authorization = "Bearer $token" } -Uri $url -Method Get
```

I get back a bunch of results that look like this:

> reportRefreshDate : 2022-08-09
>
> teamId            : 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
>
> teamName          : 12A19E853726F969FDB1377DFE59408F
>
> lastActivityDate  : 2022-08-03
>
> teamType          : Private
>
> isDeleted         : False
>
> details         : {@{activeSharedChannels=0; activeExternalUsers=0; reportPeriod=90;
> activeUsers=2; activeChannels=1; channelMessages=0; reactions=0;
> meetingsOrganized=0; postMessages=0; replyMessages=0;
> urgentMessages=0; mentions=0; guests=0}}

In this example, I have 1580 results, but they all have the same teamId (00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000) and different, random values for teamName (that is to say that none of the team names are actually names of our groups/teams).

I can get groups with:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?`$filter=resourceProvisioningOptions/Any(x:x eq 'Team')
```

What is going on with this activity report?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue as you.

This fixes it:
https://blog.atwork.at/post/Get-the-latest-Teams-activity-with-Graph

Comment: Please update your answer with at least the essentials of the solution. If the link would die, your answer would die with it.